# org.json.JSONException: Value < of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: java, php, android

this is a Json encode from mysql database:

```
[
   {"id":"1","title":"test_worked","desc":"the first project","done":"0"},
   {"id":"2","title":"mohsen","desc":"Zikey01","done":"1"},
   {"id":"3","title":"ms","desc":"tl","done":"1"}
]
```

this is my code. but have an eror org.json.JSONException: Value < of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

class ReadJSON extends AsyncTask {

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    InputStream jsonStream = getStreamFromURL(url1, "GET");
    String jsonString = streamToString(jsonStream);
    if (jsonString!=null){
        try {
            JSONArray tasks = new JSONArray(jsonString);
            for ( int i=0;i<tasks.length();i++){
                JSONObject task =tasks.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.i("myLog1403","array is"+task.getString("desc"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("my-Log","cant use json Array");
        }
    }






    return null;
}
```

}

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "note_db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * from task";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$Output = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $record=array();
          $record['id']=$row['task_id'];
      $record['title']=$row['task_title'];
     $record['desc']=$row['task_desc'];
       $record['done']=$row['task_done'];
    
    $output[]=$record;
    }
echo json_encode($output);
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: you should add more to your question, what are you trying to do, where is your error occuring and so on.

Comment: i just wanna show "desc" in logcat. and then set to a TextView @AbhinavGauniyal

Comment: Check the string response you are receiving from the URL. It's HTML... Not JSON

Comment: @cricket_007 tell me more

Comment: and you should do parsing in postExecute method not doInBackground, though it is not cause of your problem but a suggestion

Comment: `<` is an angle bracket, not a valid JSON character. You can't parse html with a JSON parser. If you go to the URL you are trying to access in your browser, you will not see raw text. I'm guessing you are writing some PHP code in a website to read your MySQL? Try printing the value of `jsonString` and viewing it in the logcat. Tl;dr learn how to debug your app

Comment: i select mysql database by php code and then echo json_ncode that array. @cricket_007

Comment: Please add your PHP code to your question. It is the problem, not the Java code

Comment: the PHP page you are calling prints an error or HTML as output instead of JSON data expected, and you try to parse that error message that contains < , so try to open that PHP link in a PC browser, and see the result. don't call from mobile unless you have a valid JSON, if you have valid json on browser, and error still appear on mobile, then you are sending invalid request from mobile (missing param, empty param, ... etc)

Comment: @Yazan previos cm is my php code

Comment: Please find the appropriate edit link under your question to update it with your PHP. I don't want to download any file

Comment: i don't want to see PHP code, i want you to try to open that page in a browsert

Comment: @cricket_007 sorry. i update my php to question

Comment: @VivekMishra can you tell me more pls